# How to convert XML content type text tag of Multiple line into one line using Bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following XML tag and trying convert into PIPE delimited file but multiple lines content text weren't populating. Any help would be great.

Input XML tag

```
<entry>
<updated>2014-02-14T12:44:00-07:00</updated>
<id>943474234</id>
<title>sw eng</title>
<content type="text">this constantly crashes on 5S.

option volume is inconsistent. it shows something in the option list and something else when  
getting the detail.

option should volume should not show in terms of 'K', 8.7K should be 8700.

the new version has many bugs and is frustrating.
:-(</content>
<im:voteSum>0</im:voteSum>
<im:voteCount>0</im:voteCount>
<im:rating>2</im:rating>
<im:version>3.3.0.122</im:version>
</entry>
```

Expected Output

```
2014-02-14T12:44:00-07:00|943474234|sw eng|this constantly crashes on 5S. option volume is inconsistent. it shows something in the option list and something else when getting the detail. option should volume should not show in terms of 'K', 8.7K should be 8700.the new version has many bugs and is frustrating.|0|0|2|3.3.0.122|
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `<im:voteSum>` and `<im:voteCount>` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python, it's much more convenient to do this job by using BeautifulSoup.

Bash is not good at `xml` I think, but for this question, the following code may help.

1. First, use `tr` to convert all lines to one by `tr -d '\n'`.
2. Then, use `sed` to convert all `xml` tag to `|` by `sed -r 's/<[^<>]*>/|/g'`
3. And then, use `sed` to convert multi `|` to one by `sed -r 's/\|+/\|/g'`
4. Finally, delete the first `|` and replace the last `|` with `\n` by `sed -r 's/\|+/\|/g'|sed -e 's/^|//' -e 's/|$/\n/'`
5. Now, I think you will get what you want. (I did not delete `:-(` for you, leave it to you)

Suppose the input xml is in a file called `xml_in`, the total command to deal with this problem will be `cat xml_in|tr -d '\n'|sed -r 's/<[^<>]*>/|/g'|sed -r 's/\|+/\|/g'|sed -e 's/^|//' -e 's/|$/\n/'`

Answer (score 0):

How about this, you should be fine to remove the head/end `|`.

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>/|/g' file |xargs |sed 's/| |/|/g'

|2014-02-14T12:44:00-07:00|943474234|sw eng|this constantly crashes on 5S. option volume is inconsistent. it shows something in the option list and something else when getting the detail. option should volume should not show in terms of K, 8.7K should be 8700. the new version has many bugs and is frustrating. :-(|0|0|2|3.3.0.122|
```

Comment: I tried but it returns as below. |3.3.0.122|sion has many bugs and is frustrating.K, 8.7K should be 8700. something else when getting the detail.

Answer (score 0):

A **robust** solution based on an **XML parser**, **[`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)**:

```
xml sel -B -t -m '/*/*' -v 'concat(normalize-space(text()),"|")' file 2>/dev/null
```

- `sel` is `xmlstarlet`'s selection (extraction) command
- `-B` removes insignificant whitespace.
- `-t -m '/*/*' -v 'concat(normalize-space(text()),"|")'` is the extraction command that is internally translated into an XSLT document before being applied (prepend `-C` to see that document).

  - `-m '/*/*'` matches all elements at the 2nd level (the children of `entry`, in this case).
  - `-v 'concat(normalize-space(text()),"|")'` extracts values from the matching elements based on XSLT functions: `text()` represents the text contents of each matching node, `normalize-space()` normalizes interior whitespace (compress multiple spaces, replace newlines with a single space each), `concat()` is used to append `|` to each value)
  - `2>/dev/null` suppresses error messages stemming from the use of namespace prefix `im:` without having declared the corresponding namespace.

Obtaining `xmlstarlet`:

- **OSX**: Install via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with `brew install xmlstarlet`
- **Linux**: chances are that it can be installed with your platform's package manager; e.g., on Debian-based distros such as **Ubuntu**: `sudo apt-get install xmlstarlet`